# Converting a file in list format into a dictionary with multiple conditions. (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, conditional-statements

Disclaimer, sorry if I have not explicitly expressed my issue. Terminology is still new to me. Thank you in advance for reading.

alright, I have a function named

```
def pluralize(word)
```

The aim is to pluralize all nouns within a file. The output I desire is: {'plural': word_in_plural, 'status' : x}
**word_in_plural** is the pluralized version of the input argument **(word)** and **x** is a string which can have one of the following values; **'empty_string', 'proper_noun', 'already_in_plural', 'success'.**

My code so far looks like..

```
filepath = '/proper_noun.txt'

def pluralize(word):
  proper_nouns = [line.strip() for line in open (filepath)]     ### reads in file as list when function is called
  dictionary = {'plural' : word_in_plural, 'status', : x}       ### defined dictionary 
    if word == '':                                              ### if word is an empty string, return values; 'word_in_plural = '' and x = 'empty_string'
      dictionary['plural'] = ''
      dictionary['status'] = 'empty_string'
      return dictionary
```

what you can see above is my attempt at writing a condition that returns a value specified if the word is an empty string.

The next goal is to create a condition that if **word** is already in plural (assuming it ends with 's' 'es' 'ies' .. etc), then the function returns a dictionary with the values: **word_in_plural = word and x = 'already_in_plural'. So the input word remains untouched. eg. (input: apartments, output: apartments)

```
    if word ### is already in plural (ending with plural), function returns a dictionary with values; word_in_plural = word and x = 'already_in_plural'
```

any ideas on how to read the last characters of the string to implement the rules ? I also very much doubt the logic.

Thank you for your input SOF community.

Answer (score 0):

You can index the word by -1 to get its last character. You can slice a string to get the the last two [-2:] or last three [-3:] characters

```
last_char = word[-1]
last_three_char = word[-3:]
```

Comment: The goal is to match all possible plural forms of words,  to the end of each string. It works for a default parameter, but when considering all possibiltiies. Iam wondering if there is a clever way of doing this. Perhaps I am overthinking it.

Comment: You can use a conditional statement like: if word[-1] == "s" or word[-2:] == "es" or word[-3:] == "ies" or ...  Of course, it will not catch irregular plurals like "geese" and will erroneously count words like "Mars" as pleural.  To truly capture plurals you need a much more sophisticated algorithm and an dictionary of English plurals.

Comment: yes pakpe,  ive implemented these ideas. Im making a strong assumption with [-1] == s. Its more of a task of implementing logic rather than a legit pluralisation.